# Formatting Time 12 Hour Clock for MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

How could a string be formatted depending an am/pm value so it could then be passed through strtotime and date?

I have a form with two inputs and one select element.

- Hour (input) <- (String) from 1 through 12
- Minute (input) <- (String) from 0 through 59
- AM/PM (select) <- (String) am or pm

Need to insert to MySql type DATETIME which needs formatting to be **current day + user selected time**.

Possible String: '2:34:pm' which for insert formatted to '2012-03-22 14:34:00'

I read possible duplicate question, but I believe was difference scenario.

Comment: Shouldn't hour be `1` through `12` and minute be `0` through `59`?

Comment: Thanks so much @mellamokb for the edit, it definitely looks much better.

Comment: You can select the current date in PHP and append it to user entered time. Then use date_format to convert.

Comment: The format you could use is '%m-%d-%Y %h:%i %p'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your variables are named `$hour`, `$minute`, and `$ampm`:

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d')
          . sprintf(
                ' %02d:%02d:00',
                ($ampm == 'pm' ? ($hour % 12) + 12 : $hour % 12),
                $minute
            );
```

Comment: `($ampm == 'pm' ? $hour + 12 : $hour)` doesn't work for the 12's.  12 am becomes `12`, but it should be `0`, and 12 pm becomes `24`, but it should be `12`.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**
Generate UNIX timestamp (number of seconds since January 1, 1970).

```
$time = mktime($_POST["hour"], $_POST["minute"], 0);
```

`$_POST["hour"]` should be in 24-hour format. You'll need to do basic input checking to ensure the values for `$_POST["hour"]` and `$_POST["minute"]` are valid.

**To convert 12-hour to 24-hour time:**

```
if ($_POST["ampm"] == "pm")
    $_POST["hour"] = ($_POST["hour"] % 12) + 12;
```

---

**Step 2**
Store to MySQL.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (date) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME($time))");
```

[FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) will convert PHP's UNIX timestamp to a perfectly-formatted MYSQL date.

Presto!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I would expect that it's because the question states that the form has an 12-hour hour field.

Comment: @cbuckley, good point. I assumed the conversion was simple enough, but I've added it to my answer.